# pydub export not working

Tags: python-2.7, pydub

I found this pydub example here on github :

```
    from pydub import AudioSegment
    from pydub.silence import split_on_silence

    sound_file = AudioSegment.from_wav("testsample.wav")
    audio_chunks = split_on_silence(sound_file,
       # must be silent for at least half a second
         min_silence_len=500,

       # consider it silent if quieter than -16 dBFS
         silence_thresh=-16
    )

    for i, chunk in enumerate(audio_chunks):

        out_file = ".//splitAudio//chunk{0}.wav".format(i)
        print "exporting", out_file
        chunk.export(out_file, format="wav")
```

It should do exactly what I want, split an audio file on silent parts.
However I can't seem to actually get it to export.
While debugging i found that it doesn't seem to get into the for loop. When I put the for loop in a try except and print the exception, i get an expection saying "start".
Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks a lot!